# Why does Selenium and geckodriver work when run using airflow test but raises an error when running inside a DAG run?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, airflow, geckodriver

I'm running a web scraping scripts using Python, Selenium and Geckodriver.
The problem is: when I run a task test using `airflow test scrape_dag scrape_data 2020-01-01` everything works just fine and the file I want is downloaded correctly. However, when I trigger a DAG run in Airflow web it fails to run.

At first Airflow couldn't access the geckodriver.log so I changed the path for one that is accessible. So the error changed to not being able to find Firefox. After that, I got that my executable is not an executable. I'm still looking for possible solutions for any of those steps.

The PythonOperator code that runs fine when testing is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver path', log_path='log path', options=options)
driver.get(url)
```

**EDIT:**
Adding the error messages for each situation.

Setting executable path and log path: `Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line`.

Also tried this:

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')
firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox_binary, log_path='log path', options=options)
driver.get(url)
```

And I get `'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.` Which I already added to path, but maybe I'm doing something wrong. Using this method also breaks the code when running `airflow test`.

**Stack traces:**

When running using geckodriver (the original implementation):

```
*** Reading local file: /home/observatorio/airflow/logs/energia_cg_dag/scrap_dados/2021-02-04T16:05:06.663528+00:00/1.log
[2021-02-04 13:05:17,474] {taskinstance.py:670} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: energia_cg_dag.scrap_dados 2021-02-04T16:05:06.663528+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-02-04 13:05:17,486] {taskinstance.py:670} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: energia_cg_dag.scrap_dados 2021-02-04T16:05:06.663528+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-02-04 13:05:17,486] {taskinstance.py:880} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-02-04 13:05:17,486] {taskinstance.py:881} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2021-02-04 13:05:17,486] {taskinstance.py:882} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-02-04 13:05:17,497] {taskinstance.py:901} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): scrap_dados> on 2021-02-04T16:05:06.663528+00:00
[2021-02-04 13:05:17,503] {standard_task_runner.py:54} INFO - Started process 5151 to run task
[2021-02-04 13:05:17,542] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'energia_cg_dag', 'scrap_dados', '2021-02-04T16:05:06.663528+00:00', '--job_id', '2281', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/energia_cg_dag.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmpgzryaz90']
[2021-02-04 13:05:17,543] {standard_task_runner.py:78} INFO - Job 2281: Subtask scrap_dados
[2021-02-04 13:05:17,565] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: energia_cg_dag.scrap_dados 2021-02-04T16:05:06.663528+00:00 [running]> ci-dobser-51091
[2021-02-04 13:05:19,534] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 984, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/observatorio/projetos/Chico-2.0/energia/capacidade_geracao/web_scraping.py", line 47, in scrap_dados
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/observatorio/projetos/Chico-2.0/utils/drivers/geckodriver', log_path='/tmp/geckodriver.log', options=options)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line

[2021-02-04 13:05:19,570] {taskinstance.py:1194} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=energia_cg_dag, task_id=scrap_dados, execution_date=20210204T160506, start_date=20210204T160517, end_date=20210204T160519
[2021-02-04 13:05:22,470] {local_task_job.py:102} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Running using the firefox binary as argument for the webdriver:

```
*** Reading local file: /home/observatorio/airflow/logs/energia_cg_dag/scrap_dados/2021-02-04T16:48:29.730315+00:00/1.log
[2021-02-04 13:48:38,335] {taskinstance.py:670} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: energia_cg_dag.scrap_dados 2021-02-04T16:48:29.730315+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-02-04 13:48:38,346] {taskinstance.py:670} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: energia_cg_dag.scrap_dados 2021-02-04T16:48:29.730315+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-02-04 13:48:38,346] {taskinstance.py:880} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-02-04 13:48:38,346] {taskinstance.py:881} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2021-02-04 13:48:38,346] {taskinstance.py:882} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-02-04 13:48:38,355] {taskinstance.py:901} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): scrap_dados> on 2021-02-04T16:48:29.730315+00:00
[2021-02-04 13:48:38,357] {standard_task_runner.py:54} INFO - Started process 31798 to run task
[2021-02-04 13:48:38,371] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'energia_cg_dag', 'scrap_dados', '2021-02-04T16:48:29.730315+00:00', '--job_id', '2284', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/energia_cg_dag.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmpz3klaxu5']
[2021-02-04 13:48:38,371] {standard_task_runner.py:78} INFO - Job 2284: Subtask scrap_dados
[2021-02-04 13:48:38,391] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: energia_cg_dag.scrap_dados 2021-02-04T16:48:29.730315+00:00 [running]> ci-dobser-51091
[2021-02-04 13:48:39,291] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver': 'geckodriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 984, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/observatorio/projetos/Chico-2.0/energia/capacidade_geracao/web_scraping.py", line 48, in scrap_dados
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox_binary, log_path='/tmp/geckodriver.log', options=options)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 

[2021-02-04 13:48:39,310] {taskinstance.py:1194} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=energia_cg_dag, task_id=scrap_dados, execution_date=20210204T164829, start_date=20210204T164838, end_date=20210204T164839
[2021-02-04 13:48:43,340] {local_task_job.py:102} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Passing the driver path and the Firefox binary path:

```
*** Reading local file: /home/observatorio/airflow/logs/energia_cg_dag/scrap_dados/2021-02-04T17:27:33.734991+00:00/1.log
[2021-02-04 14:27:46,858] {taskinstance.py:670} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: energia_cg_dag.scrap_dados 2021-02-04T17:27:33.734991+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-02-04 14:27:46,876] {taskinstance.py:670} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: energia_cg_dag.scrap_dados 2021-02-04T17:27:33.734991+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-02-04 14:27:46,876] {taskinstance.py:880} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-02-04 14:27:46,876] {taskinstance.py:881} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2021-02-04 14:27:46,876] {taskinstance.py:882} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-02-04 14:27:46,888] {taskinstance.py:901} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): scrap_dados> on 2021-02-04T17:27:33.734991+00:00
[2021-02-04 14:27:46,890] {standard_task_runner.py:54} INFO - Started process 58187 to run task
[2021-02-04 14:27:46,907] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'energia_cg_dag', 'scrap_dados', '2021-02-04T17:27:33.734991+00:00', '--job_id', '2302', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/energia_cg_dag.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmpyetrn10i']
[2021-02-04 14:27:46,907] {standard_task_runner.py:78} INFO - Job 2302: Subtask scrap_dados
[2021-02-04 14:27:46,930] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: energia_cg_dag.scrap_dados 2021-02-04T17:27:33.734991+00:00 [running]> ci-dobser-51091
[2021-02-04 14:27:47,719] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - 
[2021-02-04 14:27:47,720] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - 
[2021-02-04 14:27:47,720] {logging_mixin.py:112} WARNING - [WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[2021-02-04 14:27:47,720] {logger.py:22} INFO - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[2021-02-04 14:27:48,073] {logging_mixin.py:112} WARNING - [WDM] - Driver [/home/observatorio/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/linux64/v0.29.0/geckodriver] found in cache
[2021-02-04 14:27:48,073] {logger.py:12} INFO - Driver [/home/observatorio/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/linux64/v0.29.0/geckodriver] found in cache
[2021-02-04 14:27:48,181] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 984, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/observatorio/projetos/Chico-2.0/energia/capacidade_geracao/web_scraping.py", line 50, in scrap_dados
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), firefox_binary=firefox_binary, log_path='/tmp/geckodriver.log', options=options)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/observatorio/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127

[2021-02-04 14:27:48,183] {taskinstance.py:1194} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=energia_cg_dag, task_id=scrap_dados, execution_date=20210204T172733, start_date=20210204T172746, end_date=20210204T172748
[2021-02-04 14:27:51,862] {local_task_job.py:102} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Comment: After _...couldn't access the geckodriver.log..._ and _...not being able to find Firefox..._ which error are you seeing now?

Comment: what is the error? Where is the Airflow part in the code you provided? is that a python script you schedule with BashOperator? Please add more information.

Comment: It is a Python script that is called with PythonOperator. The Airflow DAG part of the code is just a sequence of tasks, all of them with PythonOperators or BranchPythonOperators.

Comment: @Elad: added some more info.

Comment: @Liadz when you execute your code without airflow (but on the same machine), as pure python code. is it working? This doesn't feel like airflow issue.

Comment: @Elad wrote a main function here just to test a run using `python web_scraping.py` and it runs just fine.

Comment: @Liadz please add the full traceback from airflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228264/discussion-between-liadz-and-elad).

Comment: @Liadz Didn't you have to use the firefox_binary param as well? As far I can see, you're only using the executable_path param.

Answer (score 1):

So, I was finally able to make it work.
The solution I've found is more of a workaround than anything, but it solved my problem for now.

Since my code was working outside Airflow I decided to try to run it within a BashOperator instead of a PythonOperator, as I saw some people suggesting to be done for similar problems.

At first I was having problem running bash getting the error message: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bash': 'bash'`. Which happened because I was missing the correct configuration inside my airflow-scheduler.service file.

The solution that solved that for me was: [Airflow BashOperator can't find Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58847124/airflow-bashoperator-cant-find-bash).
After I added the path `:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin` to my service file and restarted my scheduler bash started working.

The Selenium code now looks like this:

```
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), log_path='/tmp/geckodriver.log', options=options)
driver.get(url)
```

I'm using the lib webdriver-manager now just because I want to avoid using absolute paths as much as possible in my code, but the original code works as it is.

As for the task instantiation, I'm doing it like this:

```
scrape_data_task = BashOperator(task_id='scrape_data', bash_command='python /absolute/path/to/python/script/web_scraping.py')
```

Comment: You answer helped me over pulling my hair